# Get LNK1104 when trying to make a project using Qt5, OpenCV 2.4.9 with VC2013 compiler

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2013, qt-creator

Before posting this question I've already searched around many tutorials, however, all of them is outdated, or using mingw64 as the compiler.

I have add the opencv/build/x64/bin into the system path and I have no problem when working with a new project in VS2013 (with Qt5 and opencv 2.4.9 included).

Eventually, I still want to try with qt creator, since it's quite clean to package and deliever the sources of project to my partner.

I tried adding the following lines in the .pro file of my test project:

```
# OPENCV
OPENCV_BUILD_PATH = "D:/opencv/build"
OPENCV_INCLUDE_PATH = "$${OPENCV_BUILD_PATH}/include/"

INCLUDEPATH += "$${OPENCV_INCLUDE_PATH}"
LIBS += "$${OPENCV_BUILD_PATH}/x64/vc12/bin/*.dll"
LIBS += "$${OPENCV_BUILD_PATH}/x64/vc12/lib/*.lib"
LIBS += -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249
```

While linking I get this error:

**error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin.obj'**

I know that there should be some steps or some options have to be done in project settings file, but don't really know how, since mingw64 and vc12 compiler are different and I don't know much about the options of them.

It would be nice if you can help me figure out how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest to switch to CMake for project organization. Less headaches, more automatization, portability on different platforms/compilers.

Comment: Are you aware that your `OPENCV_BUILD_PATH` sais `E:...` but your error `D:...`?

Comment: Um, no, it's just a mistake when I'm not typing the right path here. It's on the D driver btw. :/

Comment: @blackibiza Yeah, I also think of that before, do you have any detail guide to follow with? And I'm not do any rebuild opencv stuff, just using the library for my research. Many guides on the net are going to  use CMake to configure opencv project before building it.

Comment: @BrianNg well the official CMake webpage and Wiki contains some examples, also with Qt. Or you might try KDAB website  (http://www.kdab.com/using-cmake-with-qt-5/) . For OpenCV, they provide a small guide too: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorial/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

On Windows, you need to set environment variables such as OpenCV_DIR, QT_DIR.

Answer (score 1):

try to change your LIBS lines. (no, you don't want to link dlls, also i doubt if wildcards are acceptable, and you're missing a -L thing for the path to the libs)

```
LIBS += -L"$${OPENCV_BUILD_PATH}/x64/vc12/lib
LIBS += -lopencv_core249 -lopencv_highgui249 -lopencv_imgproc249
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work either. I've tried using direct path instead, but no luck. Btw, qt can include the header files, so wildcards are acceptable by qmake.

Comment: ^^ do not confuse header files with libs, please.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I thought you were poiting the $${OPENVV_BUILD_PATH} part. Frankly, those wildcards I referenced from other tutorial. :/

Answer (score 0):

After long time not touching this, I return back, delete every directory that Qt Creator made before, it seems running clean all and rebuild all did not do the complete clean. After that I try to run qmake and the error disappears.

Running qmake to refresh project configuration is seriously necessary, and at that time I think that qmake would be automatically run when the .pro file being edited/saved. But I was wrong, then doing it manually solved the problem.